# Deleting unused variable causes code to crash

Tags: c, unused-variables

So I'm trying to load the s-records from a .s19 file into memory for an assignment I'm working on, and its working.  However, when I delete an unused array from my code, everything stops working and crashes.

The unused array is:

```
char test[65536];
```

And this is the loader I've written:

```
void loader(FILE * srec)
{
    char instring[SREC_LEN];
    char test[65536]; // This isn't used, but the program crashes without it for some reason
    int i=0;
    int j=0, k,l;
    while (fgets(instring, SREC_LEN, srec) != NULL)
    {

        while(instring[i] != '\n') // Counts the characters in the s-record
        {
            i++;

        }
        j = j+i;
        for(k=0;k<=i;k++) // Puts the records into memory
        {
            memory[l] = instring[k];
            l++;
        }
        l = j;

    }
    #ifdef DEBUG
    printf("MEMORY: %s",memory);
    #endif // DEBUG
}
```

If you could help me to understand why this is happening, I would appreciate it.

Comment: Seems undefined behavior case. What is `memory`?

Comment: `l` is uninitialized. and `i` need reset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has undefined behavior, it only works by sheer luck:

`fgets()` may return without writing a newline character into the buffer if `EOF` is reached prematurely. So you should at least account for that in your loop. Also you never reset `i` to 0, which you should. Change this:

```
    while(instring[i] != '\n') // Counts the characters in the s-record
    {
        i++;

    }
```

to:

```
    i = 0;
    while(instring[i] != '\n' && instring[i] != '\0') // Counts the characters in the s-record
    {
        i++;

    }
```

`l` is never initialized; you are probably writing out of bounds in `memory`. Initialize `l` to 0:

```
int j = 0, k, l = 0;
```

(I assume that `memory` is large enough to hold everything).

It also looks to me like you want `for(k = 0; k < i; k++)` rather than `for(k = 0; k <= i; k++)`, since `i` is the count of characters you want to copy.

You might want to use `memcpy()` instead.

Comment: @Cody Glad I could help. Weird problems like this ("when I delete this variable, the code crashes") usually mean that something else is wrong and that there is UB somewhere.